# Can one say "find sanctuary"?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, expression-choice

I'd like to use the expression *find sanctuary* instead of *find refuge*. Would it be fine?

Comment: I don't see why not. http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=find+sanctuary%2Cfound+sanctuary&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: I want your answer to be THE answer. How do I make it so?

Comment: @WarrenvanRooyen - It's important that you add as much context as much as possible in your questions. This one is lacking context at the moment and is hence very basic at the moment and may get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not

Have a look at this NGRAM

[[image: ](![enter image description here])](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=find+sanctuary%2Cfound+sanctuary&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Find refuge is used more and has less religious connotations

[Ngram of find refuge vs find sanctuary](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=find+sanctuary%2Cfind+refuge&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: You didn't compare "find sanctuary" with "find refuge". What was the motive behind comparing the present tense of the verb, find, with the simple past, found? I agree the word, *sanctuary* is a possible synonym for refuge but without any context how can you be sure?

Comment: The question was "can one say _find sanctuary_" and the answer is yes. It was not "which is used more, _find refuge_ or _find sanctuary_" so I did not see the need for a comparison. The comparison would not show the validity of saying _find sanctuary_. It does show refuge being used more http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=find+sanctuary%2Cfind+refuge&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: Fair point the OP's question was very basic and limited, there were no specifications. But if he had asked *Can one say, "find shelter"?* Your answer would still have been "I don't see why not"? It is customary for more experienced users to ask for greater detail and context.

Comment: But I was not in doubt what he meant. Find shelter is more out of the rain than out of trouble.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. The question was simple and earned a simple answer. Don't assume that complicating a situation makes you a more experienced user. You're nitpicking and also provided no clear answer yourself. Your involvement on this question is self-serving.

Comment: I'm nit-picking, am I? I'm not an experienced user, but mplunjan is, and from my limited time on the website, I'm not the first to ask users to explain a question slightly more in depth. I was expressing my surprise that mplunjan should back up his answer with a Ngram viewer graph which compared etc.. etc.. I am allowed to express curiosity and doubt in a civilized manner, am I not? I did not down-vote his answer either.

Comment: I have no problem with the comment which is relevant - in this case I interpreted the question literally "can I use" and decided that "yes you can" was too little. The ngram was to show it existed and how people had used the expression in literature. PS I have a _G_ in my name